# Block is displayed on page even though no region is selected, how is this possible?

Tags: blocks, theming

I am fairly new to drupal, while doing some maintenance I came across a situation that I don't understand

[image]
A block, which is defined inside a view has no region selected, yet it appears on pages determined by the "Only the listed pages" option below

It appears in a specific region, an `<aside>` named as "region-sidebar-second"

I'm unable to find anywhere in admin, or in the code to determine that is the region where this block should appear.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Drupal 7 or 8? I'd guess that the block is being added programmatically somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me once, turns out it was added through the [context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module. So check if your site has it.

Else, could have been added through the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module or the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module. So check if you have any of these modules also.

If you have non of the above modules are installed then maybe it was added via a template file. So check your template files in your theme's template folder.

Last but not least, perhaps through a preprocess function? check your `template.php` file if on D7 or `themename.theme` file if you're on D8.

Good luck detective.

Comment: Thank you, it was hidden away in the context module as you suggested. I never would have thought to look in there